# Ошибка variable y might not have been initialized

Tags: java, android

```
try { // НАЧАЛО ЗАЩИЩЕННОГО БЛОКА

        // Чтение данных из компонент
        a = Double.parseDouble(editText_a.getText().toString().trim());
        b = Double.parseDouble(editText_b.getText().toString().trim());
        x = Double.parseDouble(editText_x.getText().toString().trim());
        // Основной алгоритм
        if (x>=4)
        {
            y = 12*((x)/(Math.pow(a, c) - b));
        }
        else if (x<4)
        {
            y = 3 * (Math.pow(a, c1)) - a * b;
        }
        // Вывод полученного значения в компонент
        textView_sum.setText(String.valueOf(y));

    } catch (Exception e) { // ЧТО ДЕЛАТЬ ЕСЛИ ВОЗНИКНЕТ ОШИБКА В БЛОКЕ МЕЖДУ "TRY" И "CATCH":

        // Вывод сообщения об ошибке
        textView_sum.setText("Неверные входные данные для расчета!");

    }  // КОНЕЦ ЗАЩИЩЕННОГО БЛОКА
```

Comment: Покажите явно где у вас проблема. В данный момент не ясно с чем у вас трудность

Comment: Скорее всего вы объявляете где-то переменную `y`, но не инициализируете ее. Ошибка возникает потому, что ваши `if-else` могут не выполниться и переменная не будет проинициализирована, а следовательно, вы не можете применить к ней метод `String.valueOf(y)`

Comment: Полагаю, это не ошибка, а предупреждение от анализатора кода, встроенного в IDE, скорее всего - из-за момента `else if (x<4)`. `if` тут лишний и сбивающий с толку (настолько, что Ваша IDE вообще не понимает, что Вы делаете). Оставьте просто `else` и проблема исчезнет. При этом на корректность кода в действительности лишний `if` никак не влияет

Comment: Все спасибо, давно не программировал просто, понял свою ошибку, убрал второе if и заработало